# Understanding Lang's Proof of Fubini's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, fubini-tonelli-theorems

This question concerns the proof of Theorem 8.4 (Fubini's Theorem part 1) on page 162 in Lang's real and functional analysis book. To understand the proof I need to give following background from the book:

Let $f:X\to E$ be a function defined on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and taking values in a Banach space $E$. First we consider step maps of the form $f=\sum_{k=1}^n v_k1_{A_k}$ with $v_k\in E$, $A_k\in \mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(A_k)<\infty$, and define the integral of such maps to be $\int_X f d\mu := \sum_{k=1}^n v_k\mu(A_k)\in E$ (we check that this definition does not depend on the step map representation of $f$). The vector space of step maps is denoted by $S(\mu,E)$ and we check that the integral is linear on this space. $S(\mu,E)$ is made into a seminormed  space by introducing the $L^1$-seminorm $\|f\|_1:=\int_X |f|d\mu$.  Next we define the space $\mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$ of maps $f:X\to E$ such that there exist a sequence $(f_n)\subset S(\mu,E)$ such that

1. $(f_n)$ is $L^1$-Cauchy
2. $f_n\to f$ for almost every $x\in X$

and we define the integral of such $f$ to be $\int_X fd\mu:=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_X f_n d\mu$ (we check that this limit exists and is independent of the chosen sequence $(f_n)$). The integral is shown to be a linear map on the vector space $\mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$. $\mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$ is made into a seminormed space by extending the $L^1$-seminorm $\|f\|_1:=\int_X |f|d\mu$ for $f\in \mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$.

Ok now I can give the statement and proof of Fubini's Theorem on page 162. The set-up is two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N},\nu)$ with product space $(X\times Y,\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N},\mu\otimes\nu)$.

**Theorem 8.4 (Fubini's Theorem, part 1).** Let $f\in \mathcal{L}(\mu\otimes\nu,E)$. Then the map $f_x$ ($x$ section of $f$) is in $\mathcal{L}(\nu,E)$ for almost all $x\in X$, the map given by $x\mapsto \int_Y f_x d\nu$ for almost all $x$ (and defined arbitrarily for other $x$) is in $\mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$, and we have $\int_{X\times Y} f d\mu\otimes\nu=\int_X \int_Y f_x d\nu d\mu$.

**Proof** (with added details of mine). Let $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ denote the rings of sets of finite measure in $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$ respectively. Then $\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}=\sigma(\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B})$ where $\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B}$ is the ring of finite disjoint unions of rectangles $A\times B$ with $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}$. Moreover $X\times Y$ is $\sigma$-finite with repect to $\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B}$. By Theorem 6.3 on page 150 of the book, it follows that the space $S(\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B},E)$ is $L^1$-dense in $\mathcal{L}(\mu\otimes\nu,E)$. Hence given $f\in \mathcal{L}(\mu\otimes\nu,E)$ there exist a sequence $(f_n)\subset S(\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B},E)$ such that $(f_n)$ is $L^1$-convergent to $f$, and is in particular $L^1$-Cauchy. Using Theorem 5.2 on page 138 we may also assume that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere (by considering a subsequence). Let $Z\in \mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}$ be a $\mu\otimes\nu$-null set outside of which $f_n\to f$ holds pointwise. Then from Lemma 8.3 on page 161 we have that $\nu(Z_x)=0$ for almost all $x$, where $Z_x$ denotes the $x$ section of $Z$. Let $S\in\mathcal{M}$ be a $\mu$-null set outside of which $\nu(Z_x)=0$. Note that we have $(f_n)_x\to f_x$ $\nu$-almost everywhere for all $x\in X\setminus S$, where $f_x$ denotes the $x$ section of $f$.

Now, for each $n$ consider the map $\Phi_n:X\to S(\mathcal{B},E)\subset \mathcal{L}(\nu,E)$ defined by $\Phi_n(x)=(f_n)_x$. We note that $\Phi_n \in S(X,\mathcal{L}(\nu,E))$, i.e. $\Phi_n$ is a step map taking values in the seminormed space $\mathcal{L}(\nu,E)$. Indeed if $f=\sum_{k=1}^n v_k1_{A_k\times B_k}$ is a step map in $S(\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B},E)$ then

$$f_x=\sum_{k=1}^n v_k 1_{B_k} 1_{A_k}(x) \hspace{0.5cm} \text{with } \hspace{0.5cm}   v_k 1_{B_k}\in S(\mathcal{B},E) $$ We note also that $(\Phi_n)$ is $L^1$-Cauchy since

$$\|\Phi_n-\Phi_m\|_1=\int_X |\Phi_n-\Phi_m| d\mu=\int_X\int_Y|(f_n)_x-(f_m)_x|d\nu d\mu=\int_{X\times Y} |f_n-f_m|d(\mu\otimes\nu) = \|f_n-f_m\|_1\to 0$$

as $n,m\to\infty$, where the third equality is because $|f_n-f_m|\in S(\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B},\mathbb{R})$ and Fubini's Theorem is easily verified to hold in this case. By the "fundamental lemma 3.1" on page 129 we may assume that $\Phi_n$ converges for almost every $x$ (using a subsequence if necessary). Let $T\in\mathcal{M}$ be a $\mu$-null set outside of which $(\Phi_n)$ converges. Then in particular we have that $x\in X\setminus T$ implies $\Phi_n(x)$ Cauchy, that is $(f_n)_x$ is $L^1$-Cauchy with respect to $\nu$.

**Fundamental lemma 3.1**.(page 129) Let $(f_n)\subset S(\mu,E)$ by an $L^1$-Cauchy sequence of step maps. Then there exist a subsequence converging almost everywhere.

**Question 1.** Here we apply the fundamental lemma to a sequence of step maps $(\Phi_n)$ taking values in a seminormed space (rather than a normed space). Is the fundamental lemma still valid in this case?

If $x\in X\setminus (S\cup T)$, then combining both previous parts we get that $(f_n)_x\to f_x$ $\nu$-almost everywhere with  $(f_n)_x$ $L^1$-Cauchy. Lang's then write:

"By Corollary 5.10 we conclude that $f_x \in \mathcal{L}(\nu,E)$ and that $(f_n)_x$ is $L^1$ convergent to $f_x$ for all $x\in X \setminus (S\cup T)$, so that $\int_Y(f_n)_xd\nu$ converges to $\int_Y f_x d\nu$".

**Corollary 5.10.**(page 142) Let $(f_n)\subset  \mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$ with $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere for some map $f:X\to E$. If there exist $C\geq0$ such that $\|f_n\|_1\leq C$ for all $n$, then $f\in \mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$ and $\|f\|_1\leq C$.

**Question 2.** I don't understand why this corollary is needed. To me it seems that  $f_x \in \mathcal{L}(\nu,E)$ for all $x\in X \setminus (S\cup T)$ by definition of the integral, since for such $x$ we have $(f_n)_x \subset S(\mathcal{B},E)$ $L^1$-Cauchy and  $(f_n)_x\to f_x$ $\nu$-almost everywhere. Hence by definition $\int_Y f_x d\nu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Y (f_n)_x d\nu$ for all $x\in X \setminus (S\cup T)$.

Now note that the map $\Psi_n:X\to E$ defined by $x\mapsto \int_Y(f_n)_x$ is a step map in $S(\mathcal{A},E)$, since it is the composition of $\Phi_n$ and the integral $\int_Y d\nu$. Lang's writes:

"One sees by repeating the argument above that $(\Psi_n)$ is $L^1$-Cauchy"

**Question 3.** Is the following calculation showing that $(\Psi_n)$ is $L^1$-Cauchy correct?

$$\|\Psi_n-\Psi_m\|_1=\int_X |\Psi_n-\Psi_m| d\mu=\int_X\bigg|\int_Y(f_n)_x-(f_m)_xd\nu\bigg| d\mu\leq \int_X\int_Y |(f_n)_x-(f_m)_x| d\nu d\mu$$$$= \int_{X\times Y} |f_n-f_m|d(\mu\otimes\nu) = \|f_n-f_m\|_1\to 0 \text{ as } n,m\to\infty$$ where I used the inequality $|\int_Xfd\mu|\leq \|f\|_1$ valid for $f\in\mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$.

Hence if we define $\Psi(x)$ to be $\int_Y f_x d\nu$ for $x\in X\setminus(S\cup T)$ and arbitrarily elsewhere we get $\Psi_n\to\Psi$ for almost every $x$ with $(\Psi_n)$ $L^1$_Cauchy. It follows (by definition of the integral) that $\Psi \in \mathcal{L}(\mu,E)$ and $\int_X \Psi d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X \Psi_n d\mu$, that is

$$\int_X \int_Y f_x d\nu d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X \int_Y (f_n)_x d\nu d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X\times Y} f_n d(\mu\otimes \nu)=\int_{X\times Y} f d(\mu\otimes \nu)$$

where the last equality is because  $(f_n)$ was initially chosen to be $L^1$-convergent to $f$.

Is anybody familiar with this Fubini's proof in Lang's book? Any help on this is very appreciated.

Comment: I am sure someone will give an answer, but in my experience Lang's books are to be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @Alphie: I would not be to harsh. Or maybe I suffer from Stockholm syndrome. Anyway, the approach of Lang to Fubini's to general (for Banach spaces) that a beginner may miss the point, for then questions of measurability are more complicated. I would recommend to focus on the real (or even complex) case of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem. Both theorems together data that in a product measure space, a measurable function is integrable iff it carrier $\{f\neq0\}$ is $\sigma$--finte and other of the interative integrals of $|f|$ exits.

Comment: @OliverDiaz What do you mean by harsh?

Comment: @Alphie: Harsh relative to what Igor Ravin says. I would not put my copy of Lang's book on a pyre. It is certainly not the book I would use to teach a class on integrations, for it is too dry but as a reference for some topics in Calculus on Banach spaces is fine.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Ah ok. I understand that Lang's book is not for beginners and that some people don't like it. I have studied the usual Lebesgue integral and Fubini's Theorem before. Am really interested in the Bochner integral and, to my knowledge, Lang's book is the only textbook where you can find Fubini's Theorem proven in this context. Do you know of other such books?

Comment: The problem, is the notion of measurability. I learnt Bocj=hner integration by learning first integration a la Daniell-Stone. Then things become kind of straight forward because the both iterated integrals may give different means (Daniell means) but then you don't care becausee there is a maximal Daniell mean that coincides with the interested means on elementary functions. Dunford & Schwartz, and Bichtellers' lectures on integration do that .